# Solving an equation with LambertW function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have function $f(x)$ which has a maximum at $x^*$ ($\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}<0$ can be shown):
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} (1-x) \log \left(\frac{2 d g x}{1-x}+1\right)$$
In the research article, the solution for $x^*$ is given as 
$$x^*=\frac{(2 d g-1)-Q(2)}{(2 d g-1) \left(Q(2)+1\right)};~\text{where}~Q(t)=W\left(\frac{d g t-1}{\exp (1)}\right)$$
where $W$ is the LambertW function.

When I get the first derivative, and make it to zero, I have
$$\frac{d g}{2 d g x-x+1}-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1-\frac{2 d g x}{x-1}\right)=0\rightarrow exp\left(\frac{2 d g}{2 d g x-x+1}\right)= \left(\frac{2 d g x-x+1}{1-x}\right)$$
But I am not sure how I can reduce this to get $x^*$.

Comment: This looks to me the BEST answer :) Thanks again !!!

Comment: You're welcome again!  I enjoyed helping.

Comment: @Dr can you pls check this as well :) : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280153/convert-an-equation-to-slove-with-lambertw-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

$$\exp\left(\frac{2 d g}{2 d g x-x+1}\right)= \left(\frac{2 d g x-x+1}{1-x}\right)$$

Next, divide both sides by $e$ to obtain

$$\exp\left(\frac{(2 d g-1)(1-x)}{2 d g x-x+1}\right)= e^{-1}\left(\frac{2 d g x-x+1}{1-x}\right)$$

Then, multiply both sides by $2dg-1$ to reveal

$$ze^z=(2dg-1)/e$$

where $z=\frac{(2 d g-1)(1-x)}{2 d g x-x+1}$.  Thus,

$$z=W\left(\frac{2dg-1}{e}\right)$$

whereupon solving for $x$ yields

$$x=\frac{(2dg-1)-W\left(\frac{2dg-1}{e}\right)}{(2dg-1)\left(1+W\left(\frac{2dg-1}{e}\right)\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks @ Dr :) The trick is that dividing by $e$ to make the argument of $\exp(\cdot)$ as similar form as in RHS which helps to separate $x$ terms :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And that division certainly facilitates things.