# Slove a complicated equation (probably with LambertW function)

Tags: calculus

For the following equation: 
$$\exp\left(\frac{2 d g}{2 d g x-x+1}\right)= \left(\frac{2 d g x-x+1}{1-x}\right)$$
the solution for $x$ is discussed in: [Solving an equation with LambertW function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267582/solving-an-equation-with-lambertw-function)

As an extension, I encountered a problem with following equation in $y$:
$$\exp\left(\frac{a b (g+1) y-a b^2}{g y (a b+y (a+1-ag))}\right)=\left(\frac{a b+y (a+1-ag)}{y}\right)$$
As this is different from the previous one, I am not able to follow same technique. I could only solve this without $gy$ term in the denominator of $\exp(\cdot)$.

Does any one have constructive idea to convert this equation in order to get the solution using the LambertW function form? or else any other alternative method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this can't be done using LambertW.  Of course the usual numerical methods are available (given numerical values of the parameters), or if some of the parameters are small you might find series expansions useful.